# Why I am not able to getProper Text Value while Viewing Gallery in my application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-gallery

In My Application i have Implement the Simple Gallery Demo.
Here i am going to set text Value according to user viewing the gallery.

Here is my Code for GetView method of Image Adapter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

        i.setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);

        /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(300, 300));

        switch(position){

        case 0:
            productName.setText("dimond540_1");

            break;
        case 1:
            productName.setText("diamond540_2");

            break;
        case 2:
            productName.setText("diamond_ink_bottle_1");

            break;
        case 3:
            productName.setText("diamond_ink_bottle_2");

            break;
        case 4:
            productName.setText("diamond_ink_bottle_3");

            break;
        case 5:
            productName.setText("micarta_1");

            break;
        case 6:
            productName.setText("micarta_2");

            break;
        case 7:
            productName.setText("vac700_1");

            break;
        case 8:
            productName.setText("vac700_2");

            break;
        }
        return i;
    }
    /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
     * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
    public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
        return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
    }
}
```

Now the Proble is, While i am viewing the gallery image, text value is change. But i am not able to get the textValue that i have set as second position and Second last position.

I have tryed many but every time i got all value but not the second position textValue and SecondLast position textValue.

So, whats wrong in my code?

Comment: This is the most weird implementation of getView I have came across :O

Comment: Your getView() is worst implemented, use some coding format how to use convertView, and how to inflate xml to it in getView() of your custom adapter.

Comment: I just want to change the text Value according to the View Gallery. and I have Solve the problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: you can use the code in the question but the convertview will cause the problem. If you debug it then also you can solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve My Question as below:

I have made the Method in that class and in that method i change the TextValue and it works great.

Code:

```
 public long getItemId(int position) { 

        switch(position){

        case 0:
            productName.setText("Dimond540(1)");

            break;
        case 1:
            productName.setText("Dimond540(2)");

            break;
        case 2:
            productName.setText("Diamond Ink Bottle(1)");

            break;
        case 3:
            productName.setText("Diamond Ink Bottle(2)");

            break;
        case 4:
            productName.setText("Diamond Ink Bottle(3)");

            break;
        case 5:
            productName.setText("Micarta(1)");

            break;
        case 6:
            productName.setText("Micarta(2)");

            break;
        case 7:
            productName.setText("Vac700(1)");

            break;
        case 8:
            productName.setText("Vac700(2)");

            break;
        }

        return position; 
    }
```